# Is it possible to have a dynamic strategy matrix in a workflow in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to specify a strategy matrix dynamically within the workflow. So, instead of:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    foo: [bar, baz]
```

I want to first call some script which will compute and return an array such as `[bar, baz]` to me, and then I want to use that as the strategy matrix.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not possible with the available GitHub Actions workflow features but it is possible with a bit hacky solution to provide all the required matrix parameter values' combinations. You can generate all the combinations as a JSON snippet in one of the previous workflow jobs and expose it as the job [`outputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) then use it with matrix [`include`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrixinclude) keyword in the next job to provide all the matrix parameters and its values' combinations using [`fromJson()`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#fromjson) function as [demonstrated in the official announcement](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-15-github-actions-new-workflow-features/#new-fromjson-method-in-expressions). To better explain the concept lets look at the example static matrix job:

```yaml
jobs:
  matrix-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        includes:
          - foo: foo-1
            bar: bar-1
          - foo: foo-1
            bar: bar-2
          - foo: foo-2
            bar: bar-1
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo foo=${{ matrix.foo }}
          echo bar=${{ matrix.bar }}
```

The workflow outcome is:

[image]

In this workflow, all the matrix parameter value combinations are statically provided. We can convert it to be dynamically provided like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  setup-matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup matrix combinations
        id: setup-matrix-combinations
        run: |
          MATRIX_PARAMS_COMBINATIONS='
              {"foo": "foo-1", "bar": "bar-1"},
              {"foo": "foo-1", "bar": "bar-2"},
              {"foo": "foo-2", "bar": "bar-1"},
          '
          echo ::set-output name=matrix-combinations::{\"include\":[$MATRIX_PARAMS_COMBINATIONS]}
    outputs:
      matrix-combinations: ${{ steps.setup-matrix-combinations.outputs.matrix-combinations }}
  matrix-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.setup-matrix.outputs.matrix-combinations) }}
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo foo=${{ matrix.foo }}
          echo bar=${{ matrix.bar }}
```

and the outcome:

[image]

The two workflows have equivalent outcomes for the `matirx-job` but the last one provides a matrix input which is generated dynamically. This is the only way you can dynamically generate a matrix build, you have to provide all the combinations on your own using [`matrix.include`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrixinclude). It's not possible (at the time of writing this) to dynamically provide an array of available values for the given matrix parameter (like in your question) but you have at least a dynamic matrix job.

Comment: When i try to use the matrix it get - Invalid type found: object was expected but string was found at this line  matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.setup-matrix.outputs.matrix-combinations) }} , Any help?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can use a matrix that is ingested from an output of a prior step that your step depends on ("needs"):

```
jobs:
  set:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{steps.list_dirs.outputs.matrix}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - id: list_dirs
        run: echo "::set-output name=matrix::$(ls|jq -cnR '[inputs | select(length>0)]')"

  get:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: set
    strategy:
      matrix:
        subdir: ${{fromJson(needs.set.outputs.matrix)}}
```

Comment: This syntax is now deprecated (https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/), new syntax would be `run: echo "matrix=$(ls|jq -cnR '[inputs | select(length>0)]')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77692848/9801139
I took a slightly different approach. I used actions/github-script@v6 (JavaScript) to achieve my goal.