# GitHub Actions: How to override the default matrix with workflow_dispatch inputs?

Tags: github-actions

If I want to let a user override the default values in the matrix, how do I do that?

Consider the following simplified example:

```yaml
name: CICD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      py_version:
        description: "Python version"
        default: "3.11"

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        py_version: [3.7, 3.10]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.py_version }}
```

I want to let a user override the `py_version` matrix list with the list provided in the `workflow_dispatch` input. Is there a way?

I tried asking ChatGPT but it messed things up all the time. I went looking for a way to dynamically build the matrix JSON, but this looks complicated and I failed to find a working solution.

PS: Is it possible to let the user provide a list-like value in the inputs, say, `[3.5, 2.7]` that would be populated in the matrix? I am fine with a single value as well, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a dynamic strategy matrix in a workflow in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65056670/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-strategy-matrix-in-a-workflow-in-github-actions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a comma-separated list along with [`format()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) and [`fromJSON()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) functions; and, [OR operator `||`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) like this:

```yaml
name: populate_matrix_from_inputs

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      python_version:
        description: 'Comma-separated list of Python versions e.g. "3.10","3.11"'
        default: '"3.11"'
        required: true

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python_version: ${{ fromJSON(format('[{0}]', inputs.python_version || '"3.7","3.10"')) }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python_version }}
```

**Inputs**

[image: inputs]

**Runs**

[image: runs]

---

**NOTE**: Quotes around versions are mandatory to avoid the removal of trailing zeros during conversions. For example, without quotes, `3.10` would become `3.1` which is not a valid version. If such cases are not an issue, quotes may be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem, this answers the subquestion in PS, thank you! Do you have any idea about the main question which was "how to override the strategy ONLY if the workflow_dispatch was used, and keep original matrix intact if the workflow was triggered automatically?

Comment: @RomanDodin: Doesn't this answer address that too? The user can input the values and those will be overridden. Or, is it something different?

Comment: @RomanDodin: After looking at `on: push` in your workflow and reading your comment again, are you referring to the case when this workflow is run by a `push` event, right? You want the original values there in that case and only use the ones in the `workflow_dispatch` inputs if it's used?

Comment: @RomanDodin: Updated answer to handle the default case in case of other events too. Working fine for both cases. Please test and verify on your side. Thanks!

Comment: thank you! This works flawlessly. I assume I can put the default value (that is the one that is used when the workflow executed automatically) in an ENV var and have it centrally managed.